# Is it normal for quicksort to take 5 hours for a 100,000,000 element array?

Tags: java, algorithm

Implementing the basic algorithm using last array as a pivot in Java, is it normal for it take  5 hours for sorting a 100,000,000 element array of random numbers?

My system Specs:
Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2 (2011)
Intel Core i5 2.3 GHz 
8GB ram

**Update2: So I think I am doing something wrong in my other methods since Narendra was able to run the quicksort. Here is the full code I am trying to run.**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class QuickSort {
public static int comparisons = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 100000000;
    int[] smallSampleArray = createArrayOfSize(size);

    System.out.println("Starting QS1...");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    quickSort(smallSampleArray,0,size-1);
    System.out.println(  "Finished QS1 in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)+ " seconds");
    System.out.println("Number of comparisons for QS1: " + comparisons);

}

public static int[] createArrayOfSize(int arraySize) {
    int[] anArray = new int[arraySize];
    Random random = new Random();

    for(int x=0; x < anArray.length; x++ ) {
        anArray[x] = random.nextInt(1000) + 1;;
    }
    return anArray;
}


public static void quickSort( int anArray[], int position, int pivot) {

    if( position < pivot ) {
        int q = partition(anArray, position, pivot);

        quickSort(anArray, position, q-1);
        quickSort(anArray, q+1, pivot);

    }

}

public static int partition(int anArray[], int position, int pivot ) {
    int x = anArray[pivot];
    int i = position - 1; 

    for(int j = position; j < (pivot-1); j++ ) {
        comparisons++;
        if(anArray[j] <= x) {
             i = i + 1;
             int temp =  anArray[i];
             anArray[i] = anArray[j];
             anArray[j] = temp;
        }

    }
    int temp = anArray[i+1];
    anArray[i+1] = anArray[pivot];
    anArray[pivot] = temp;



        return i+1;
    }

}
```

Comment: How much memory is your app consuming? Is it using swap file?

Comment: How long does using `java.util.Arrays.sort()` take on the same data set in the same environment?

Comment: Post your implementation, and we'll have a look. There are all kinds of possible ways to make quicksort slower than it ought to be.

Comment: @xanatos Java apps usually have a fixed memory limit only in physical memory. It has to be continous too.

Comment: @nfechner: How do you suppose Java overrules the OS's memory management scheme and prevents memory from being swapped?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I had to increase stack size to prevent stack overflow to 4128M (which is probably overkill), and I also increased heap space to the same value. What is a swap file? I don't think it's a swap file though.

Comment: @Doug: If you're running out of stack space you almost certainly have a bug in your algorithm.  The depth of quicksort's stack should average to about `log (100,000,000)`. It seems like you're not dividing or partitioning effectively.  Is the data already mostly sorted?  If so, you need to randomize the index to use as a pivot value.

Comment: Completely random data. I know I can randomize the pivot index, but I want to know if this is normal for a last element pivot.

Comment: I posted the code, just to let you guys know :)

Comment: Can you post the initialization code where you initialize the random array? Have you inspected the array and confirmed that is really looks random?

Comment: i don't believe you can actually wait for 5 hours !!!

Comment: I ran this bit of java code and it takes about 20 seconds with a gig of max heap allocation. `Arrays.sort` takes almost same time (22 seconds to be exact)

Comment: @Narendra Oh really? Could it be my machine? I asked my friend to run it (Macbook air), and same results.

Comment: @Dapeng I left it on overnight and outputted the execution time.

Comment: @Doug This is what I am running http://pastebin.com/BjuvcE0B and actually your sort function is running faster than `Arrays.sort` consistently. And my vm arguments are `-Xmx1500m` (as I am sorting 2 different arrays in parallel).

Comment: @Narendra I tested your code, and it works! Now I am really unsure why mine doesn't work. I updated question with my full source.

Comment: @Doug: The main difference that stands out is what values you use to populate your array.  See my updated answer for why that makes such a critical difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*I've moved the old, now irrelevant answer to the end.*

### Edit x2

Aha!  I think I've found the cause of your horrible performance.  You told us you were using randomized data.  That is true.  But what you didn't tell us is that you were using such a small range of possible random values.

For me, your code is very performant if you change this line:

```
anArray[x] = random.nextInt(1000) + 1;
```

to this:

```
anArray[x] = random.nextInt();
```

That goes against expectations, right?  It should be cheaper to sort a smaller range of values, since there should be less swaps we need to do, right?  So **why does this happen?**  This happens because you have so many elements with the same value (on average, 100 thousand).  So why does this lead to such horrible performance?  Well, say at each point you chose a *perfect* pivot value: exactly halfway.  Here's what it would look like:

```
1000 - Pivot: 500
 - 500+ - Pivot: 750
   - 750+ - Pivot: 875
   - 750- - Pivot: 625
 - 500- - Pivot: 250
```

And so on.  **However** (and here's the critical part) you would eventually get to a partition operation where *every single value is equal to the partition value*.  In other words, there will be a a **big** (100 thousand big) block of numbers with the same value that you will try to recursively sort.  And how will that happen?  It will recurse **100 thousand times**, only removing the single pivot value at each level.  In other words, it will partition **everything** to the left or everything to the right.

Expanding on the breakdown above, it would look kind of like this (I've used 8--a power of 2--for simplicity, and forgive the bad graphical representation)

```
Depth Min  Max  Pvt NumElements

0     0     7    4   100 000 000
1     0     3    2    50 000 000    
2     0     1    1    25 000 000
3     0     0    0    12 500 000 < at this point, you're
4     0     0    0    12 499 999 < no longer dividing and
5     0     0    0    12 499 998 < conquering effectively.
3     1     1    1    12 500 000
4     1     1    1    12 499 999
5     1     1    1    12 499 998
2     2     3    3    25 000 000
3     ...    
3     ...    
1     4     7    6    50 000 000    
2     4     5    5    25 000 000
3     ...
3     ...    
2     6     7    7    25 000 000
3     ...
3     ...
```

If you want to counter this, you need to optimize your code to reduce the effects of this.  More on that to come (I hope)...

...and continued.  An easy way to solve your problem is to check if the array is already sorted at each step.

```
public static void quickSort(int anArray[], int position, int pivot) {

    if (isSorted(anArray, position, pivot + 1)) {
        return;
    }

    //...
}


private static boolean isSorted(int[] a, int start, int end) {
    for (int i = start+1; i < end; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[i-1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Add that and you won't recurse unnecessarily and you should be golden.  In fact, you get better performance than you do with values randomized over all 32 bits of the integer.

---

### Old answer (for posterity only)

Your partitioning logic looks really suspect to me.  Let's extract and ignore the swap logic.  Here's what you have:

```
    int i = position - 1; 

    for(int j = position; j < pivot; j++ ) {

        if(anArray[j] <= x) {
             i = i + 1;
             swap(anArray, i, j);
        } 

    }
```

I fail to see how this would work at all.  For example, if the very first value were less than the pivot value, it would be swapped with itself?

I think you want something like this (just a rough sketch):

```
for ( int i = 0, j = pivot - 1; i < j; i++ ) {

   if ( anArray[i] > pivotValue ) {
      //i now represents the earliest index that is greater than the pivotValue,
      //so find the latest index that is less than the pivotValue
      while ( anArray[j] > pivotValue ) {
         //if j reaches i then that means that *all* 
         //indexes before i/j are less than pivot and all after are greater
         //and so we should break out here
         j--;
      }

      swap(anArray, i, j);
   }
} 

//swap pivot into correct position
swap(anArray, pivot, j+1);
```

### Edit

I think I understand the original partitioning logic now (I had confused the if-block to be looking at elements greater than the pivot).  I'll leave my answer up on the off chance that it delivers better performance but I doubt it would make a significant difference.

Comment: Exactly, it would swap itself. This is how the book teaches it, (Introduction to Algorithms 3rd edition). I guess I should improve it.

Comment: @Doug: I'm looking at it again and see how it could work.  It's not the way I'd think about partitioning but I can't say that it wouldn't work.  I also can't say that it's any non-trivial amount slower than my suggestion so take my answer with a grain of salt.  I don't want to be the source of a red herring :-).

Comment: In addition did you try getting the pivot on random basis (use Random class in Java) ?
Then see the average of 4-5 runs of this algorithm. You should get more performance improvement

Comment: Well it definitely works, but swapping itself might be the reason for it to slow down right?

Comment: @saury I have that ready to test, I will be testing it tonight before I go to bed along with a few other variations that I have setup. I really just wanted to know if it was normal for this specific case.

Comment: @Doug: It might slow things down a bit.  Given an array of size N, both partitioning strategies make N comparisons but mine will never swap if unneeded.  This might come at a cost of more complicated and less optimizable code though.  So I doubt it's a huge gain.

Comment: I updated my question, because I am still having the same problem. I think it is my other parts, but I am not sure anymore at this point.

Comment: @Doug: I've updated my answer with a description of what I think your problem is.  I don't have a concrete suggestion for you yet though.

Comment: Scratch that, I've added a suggestion as well.

Comment: EUREKA! IT WORKS ! I love you!

Comment: "This happens because you have so many elements with the same value (on average, 100 thousand)." Is that 100 thousand average number calculated or just a guess?

Comment: @Doug: Well in your code you have 100 million elements with 1000 equally probable values each.  So it's just division.

Answer (score 2):

Beeing a c# guy I just pasted the above code in an empty c# project.
It took 35 seconds to complete for an array of 100.000.000 integers.
There seems to be nothing wrong with the code, there must be something else in your environment. Is the Java process allowed to allocate ~800 MB of RAM?

What happens if you lower the array size to 10.000.000. Do you get close to ~3 seconds then?
Is there a certain array size where the sort suddenly get slow?

**Edit**

I'm almost certain that you don't have a random array, you have probably failed with your random initialization.

If you create a new Random object for each element you will typically get the same value for each element since each initialization of `Random` seeds the random generator with the current time in milliseconds. If the whole array gets initialized within the same millisecond all elements gets the same value.

In c# I initialize like this

```
Random r = new Random();
var intArr = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10000)
            select r.Next()).ToArray();
var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
quickSort(intArr, 0, intArr.Length - 1);
sw.Stop();
```

This takes 2 milliseconds to sort.

If I reinitialize my `Random` object for each element

```
var intArr = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10000)
              select (new Random()).Next()).ToArray();
```

I takes 300 milliseconds to sort because all the elements in the array gets the same value.

Comment: It works fine with 1,000,000 and 10,000,000. My runtime only includes the quicksort. The creating array process happens outside of my time recording.

Comment: @doug - so what happens at 20 million, 30 million, etc?  Does the running time go up relatively smoothly like you'd expect for a n*log(n) algorithm, or does it suddenly change at a certain point?

Comment: @Albin: Java's implementation of Random actually protects against the situation you describe.  The time in milliseconds is used to seed the random, yes, but each instantiation also increments a counter whose value is then added to the seed.  So two Randoms created in the same millisecond will indeed generate different sequences.

Comment: @MarkPeters, ah, that's a nice feature.